# Container is Exiting on start

Tags: windows, docker, cockroachdb

Following the Getting Started guide for Starting a Local Cluster in Docker https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/start-a-local-cluster-in-docker.html.  The problem is that the container immediately exits.

Tried adding `tail -f /dev/null` but it did not work.  Though pretty sure it is not supposed to be needed.

Running on Docker for Windows
Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962

Tried with -it flag and the error listed is

```
*
* WARNING: RUNNING IN INSECURE MODE!
*
* - Your cluster is open for any client that can access <all your IP addresses>.
* - Any user, even root, can log in without providing a password.
* - Any user, connecting as root, can read or write any data in your cluster.
* - There is no network encryption nor authentication, and thus no confidentiality.
*
* Check out how to secure your cluster: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v19.1/secure-a-cluster.html
*
*
* ERROR: failed to start server: could not create temp storage: could not open rocksdb instance: IO error: While fsync: a directory: Invalid argument
*
Failed running "start"
```

Comment: replace `-d` with `-it` you will get to the actual error

Comment: Please share the full docker command you used, might show a problem with volume etc.